# error while reading data form DataGridView and insert into oracle database

Tags: c#, oracle, c#-4.0, datagridview, oracle11gr2

I am trying to insert data from `DataGridView` into oracle database
for one record everything works fine, but when there is more than one row in the `DataGridView` I get below error message:

> ora-06550 line 1 column 15:
>
> pls-00306 wrong number or types of arguments in call to
>   'F_INS_ORDER_DATA'
>
> ora-06550 line 1 column 7:
>
> pl/sql statement ignored

I tried to

1. Check number of parameters but they are okay since one record inserted successfully
2. there is no wrong type of parameter but they are okay because one record inserted successfully
3. I checked if arguments are in the wrong order but they are okay also because one record inserted successfully

Code:

```
string connstr = @"Data Source=orcl; User Id=user; password=pwd;";

string insertcmdtxt = @"F_INS_ORDER_DATA";   

using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(connstr))
using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(insertcmdtxt, conn))
{
    try
    {
        conn.Open();

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        cmd.CommandText = insertcmdtxt;

        cmd.Parameters.Add(":vORDER_ID", OracleDbType.Int32, ParameterDirection.ReturnValue);

        foreach (DataGridViewRow Row in DGV_INVOICE.Rows)
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":P_CUSTOMER_ID", OracleDbType.Int32)).Value     = TB_CUSTOMER_ID.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":P_ORDER_NOTE", OracleDbType.Varchar2)).Value   = TB_ORDER_NOTE.Text;

            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":P_PRODUCT_ID", OracleDbType.Int32)).Value      = Row.Cells[DGV_INVOICE.Columns["DGV_PRODUCT_ID"].Index].Value;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":P_UNIT_PRICE", OracleDbType.Int32)).Value      = Row.Cells[DGV_INVOICE.Columns["DGV_UNIT_PRICE"].Index].Value;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":P_QUANTITY", OracleDbType.Int32)).Value        = Row.Cells[DGV_INVOICE.Columns["DGV_QUANTITY"].Index].Value;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":P_DISCOUNT", OracleDbType.Int32)).Value        = Row.Cells[DGV_INVOICE.Columns["DGV_DISCOUNT"].Index].Value;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":P_ORDER_STATUS", OracleDbType.Varchar2)).Value = '1';
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":P_ITEM_NOTE", OracleDbType.Varchar2)).Value    = Row.Cells[DGV_INVOICE.Columns["DGV_ITEM_NOTE"].Index].Value;
        }

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        TB_INVOICE_ID.Text = (cmd.Parameters[":vORDER_ID"].Value).ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception EX)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(EX.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        return;
    }
}
}'
```

**Code Update**

After testing suggestion from friends below

Now I am not getting any error but if there is more than one row in the database 
I found one record inserted only

```
string connstr = @"Data Source=orcl; User Id=user; password=pwd;";
                string insertcmdtxt = @"F_INS_ORDER_DATA";  

                using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(connstr))
                using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(insertcmdtxt, conn))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        conn.Open();

                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                        cmd.CommandText = insertcmdtxt;

                        foreach (DataGridViewRow Row in DGV_INVOICE.Rows)
                        {
                            cmd.Parameters.Clear();

                            cmd.Parameters.Add(":vORDER_ID", OracleDbType.Int32, ParameterDirection.ReturnValue);

                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":P_CUSTOMER_ID", OracleDbType.Int32)).Value     = TB_CUSTOMER_ID.Text;
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":P_ORDER_NOTE", OracleDbType.Varchar2)).Value   = TB_ORDER_NOTE.Text;

                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":P_PRODUCT_ID", OracleDbType.Int32)).Value      = Row.Cells[DGV_INVOICE.Columns["DGV_PRODUCT_ID"].Index].Value;
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":P_UNIT_PRICE", OracleDbType.Int32)).Value      = Row.Cells[DGV_INVOICE.Columns["DGV_UNIT_PRICE"].Index].Value;
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":P_QUANTITY", OracleDbType.Int32)).Value        = Row.Cells[DGV_INVOICE.Columns["DGV_QUANTITY"].Index].Value;
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":P_DISCOUNT", OracleDbType.Int32)).Value        = Row.Cells[DGV_INVOICE.Columns["DGV_DISCOUNT"].Index].Value;
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":P_ORDER_STATUS", OracleDbType.Varchar2)).Value = '1';
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":P_ITEM_NOTE", OracleDbType.Varchar2)).Value    = Row.Cells[DGV_INVOICE.Columns["DGV_ITEM_NOTE"].Index].Value;
                        }

                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();                        

                        TB_INVOICE_ID.Text = (cmd.Parameters[":vORDER_ID"].Value).ToString();
                    }
                    catch (Exception EX)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(EX.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                        return;
                    }
                }
```

Comment: You keep adding parameters again for every row.  Only need to do that once, then in loop, just change the parameter values (and include ExecuteNonQuery() in the loop).

Comment: As @OldProgrammer says, plus either clear your parameters at the top of the loop (`cmd.Parameters.Clear();`) or do declarations before the loop and change values inside the loop (`cmd.Parameters[":P_PRODUCT_ID"].Value = Row.Cells...;`).

Comment: @SteveGreene  uh then which one is better clearing parameters or changing values ?

Comment: @OldProgrammer thanks  a lot

Comment: I wouldn't think it would be a performance issue, so I would just do a clear.

Comment: @SteveGreene then claering parameters will be Easier 
`cmd.Parameters.Clear()` at the top of the loop I get error message says ora-06550 line 1 column 7:
pls-00221:'F_INS_ORDER_DATA' is not a procedure or is undefined
ora-06550 line 1 column 7:
pl/sql statement ignored

Comment: Move vORDER_ID after the clear.

Comment: @SteveGreene it insert one record when there is more than one record at  `DataGridView` tried to use `MessageBox.Show(DGV_INVOICE.RowCount.ToString());` to see count if its correct it shows correct count but it seems its not looping it insert one record

Comment: @SteveGreene it loops twice since message show up twice when there are two record but it insert one record.. so it is looping but i dont know why it is not insert one record

Comment: @OldProgrammer any idea about the issue ?

Comment: If you have made changes to your code as suggested, and a different problem is showing, then please open a *new* question with the [mcve].  Thanks.

Comment: @OldProgrammer thank you please if you dont mind to take a look here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41813535/only-one-record-inserted-into-oracle-database-from-datagridview I guess I found the problem but I need a lite help thanks in advance