# Only one record inserted into Oracle database from datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview, oracle11gr2

I am trying to read data from `DataGridView` and insert it into database. Everything works fine when one record is in the `DataGridView`, but when there is more than one record within the `DataGridView` I got only one record inserted and all other records are not inserted into database.

I have attached the Oracle function code for more details.

I think the issue caused by function since the first `table order` should have one record and the sub `table order_details` should have the list of purchased items. So the function execute once and then  stop because of primary key exception on the first `table (Order)`.

I don't know if that is right but in case it is right then how to solve and keep thing happen in one transaction so all transaction will success, or it will rollback all things has been done before?

```
string connstr = @"Data Source=orcl; User Id=user; password=pwd;";
                string insertcmdtxt = @"F_INS_ORDER_DATA";   

                using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(connstr))
                using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(insertcmdtxt, conn))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        conn.Open();

                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                        cmd.CommandText = insertcmdtxt;

                        foreach (DataGridViewRow Row in DGV_INVOICE.Rows)
                        {
                            cmd.Parameters.Clear();

                            cmd.Parameters.Add(":vORDER_ID", OracleDbType.Int32, ParameterDirection.ReturnValue);

                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":P_CUSTOMER_ID", OracleDbType.Int32)).Value     = TB_CUSTOMER_ID.Text;
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":P_ORDER_NOTE", OracleDbType.Varchar2)).Value   = TB_ORDER_NOTE.Text;

                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":P_PRODUCT_ID", OracleDbType.Int32)).Value      = Row.Cells[DGV_INVOICE.Columns["DGV_PRODUCT_ID"].Index].Value;
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":P_UNIT_PRICE", OracleDbType.Int32)).Value      = Row.Cells[DGV_INVOICE.Columns["DGV_UNIT_PRICE"].Index].Value;
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":P_QUANTITY", OracleDbType.Int32)).Value        = Row.Cells[DGV_INVOICE.Columns["DGV_QUANTITY"].Index].Value;
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":P_DISCOUNT", OracleDbType.Int32)).Value        = Row.Cells[DGV_INVOICE.Columns["DGV_DISCOUNT"].Index].Value;
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":P_ORDER_STATUS", OracleDbType.Varchar2)).Value = '1';
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":P_ITEM_NOTE", OracleDbType.Varchar2)).Value    = Row.Cells[DGV_INVOICE.Columns["DGV_ITEM_NOTE"].Index].Value;

                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }

                        TB_INVOICE_ID.Text = (cmd.Parameters[":vORDER_ID"].Value).ToString();
                    }
                    catch (Exception EX)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(EX.Message, "حدث خطاء", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                        return;
                    }
                }
```

**function Code**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION F_INS_Order_Data (P_CUSTOMER_ID     IN NUMBER,
                                                                                       P_ORDER_NOTE       IN VARCHAR2,
                                                                                       P_PRODUCT_ID        IN NUMBER,
                                                                                       P_UNIT_PRICE         IN NUMBER,
                                                                                       P_QUANTITY           IN NUMBER,
                                                                                       P_DISCOUNT           IN NUMBER,
                                                                                       P_ORDER_STATUS  IN VARCHAR2,
                                                                                       P_ITEM_NOTE         IN VARCHAR2)
   RETURN NUMBER
IS
   VOrder_Id      NUMBER;                --ORDER_ID Filled by trigger
   vCreated_by   VARCHAR2 (64)         := 'SYSTEM';
   vCreated_On   DATE                        := SYSDATE;

   sql_stmt           VARCHAR2 (4000);
   ERR_CODE      VARCHAR2(64);
   ERR_MSG       VARCHAR2(1024);

BEGIN

    SAVEPOINT Setp1;

    sql_stmt := 'INSERT INTO orders (ORDER_ID,
                                                          CUSTOMER_ID,
                                                          NOTES,
                                                          CREATED_BY,
                                                          CREATED_ON)
                                            VALUES (NULL,                       --ORDER_ID Filled by trigger
                                                          :PCUSTOMER_ID,    --CUSTOMER_ID
                                                          :POrderNote,            --NOTES
                                                          :PCREATED_BY,       --CREATED_BY
                                                          :PCREATED_ON)     --CREATED_ON
                      RETURNING ORDER_ID INTO :vORDER_ID';

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_stmt USING P_CUSTOMER_ID,
                                                                   P_ORDER_NOTE,
                                                                   vCreated_by,
                                                                   vCreated_ON
                      RETURNING INTO vORDER_ID;

    --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (sql_stmt);    /* For Testing Purpose */


    sql_stmt:='INSERT INTO ORDER_DETAILS (ORDER_ID,
                                                                           PRODUCT_ID,
                                                                           UNIT_PRICE,
                                                                           QUANTITY,
                                                                           DISCOUNT,
                                                                           ORDER_STATUS,
                                                                           NOTES,
                                                                           CREATED_BY,
                                                                           CREATED_ON)
                                                           VALUES ( :PvORDER_ID,              --ORDER_ID,
                                                                           :PPRODUCT_ID,          --PRODUCT_ID
                                                                           :PUNIT_PRICE,           --UNIT_PRICE
                                                                           :PQUANTITY,             --QUANTITY
                                                                           :PDISCOUNT,             --DISCOUNT
                                                                           :PORDER_STATUS,    --ORDER_STATUS
                                                                           :PItem_Note,                 --NOTES
                                                                           :PCREATED_BY,          --CREATED_BY
                                                                           :PCREATED_ON         --CREATED_ON
                                                                          )';

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_stmt USING vORDER_ID,
                                                                   P_PRODUCT_ID,
                                                                   P_UNIT_PRICE,
                                                                   P_QUANTITY,
                                                                   P_DISCOUNT,
                                                                   P_ORDER_STATUS,
                                                                   P_ITEM_NOTE,
                                                                   vCreated_by,
                                                                   vCreated_On;

   --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (sql_stmt);    /* For Testing Purpose */

   RETURN (VOrder_Id);

EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN 

    ROLLBACK TO Setp1;

    ERR_CODE := SQLCODE;
    ERR_MSG := SUBSTR(SQLERRM, 1, 1024);

    sql_stmt := F_INS_ERROR_LOG(SYSDATE,                        --P_ERROR_TIME,
                                                       vCreated_by,                    --P_USER_ID,
                                                       'F_INS_Order_Data',      --P_PROGRAM_UNIT,
                                                       NULL,                              --P_ERROR_LOCATION,
                                                       NULL,                             --P_KEY_DATA_DESC,
                                                       ERR_CODE,                    --P_ERROR_CODE,
                                                       ERR_MSG);                    --P_ERROR_MSG)';

RETURN -1;

END F_INS_Order_Data;
/
```

Comment: You proc is adding an ORDER and ORDER_DETAILS on every call, but you only want the ORDER once so you will need to change your logic. You could move your `TB_INVOICE_ID.Text =` inside the loop after the `ExecuteNonQuery()` call then if it has a value send it in as a parameter and change your proc to test if it is passed in or null. Otherwise, make 2 procs (Add_Order, Add_Order_Details).

Comment: @SteveGreene  I used one function to force Rollback to rollback all changes in case of any error to avoid in-doubt transactions and risk of incomplete transactions... if i make two function as us suggestion then how I am able rollback all changes done by first and second function ?
and how to make c# execute both function in one transaction ?

Comment: Not sure in Oracle when triggers are involved. You could go the first option and return the Order Id when it is created and then pass that in on 2nd and subsequent iterations. Change logic in proc to only insert order when it is not passed in (null).

Answer (score 0):

This is not necessarily the issue but.  cmd.Parameters.Add(":vORDER_ID", OracleDbType.Int32, ParameterDirection.ReturnValue);
You are not using orderid in your proceuder and you are passing it in.

Second,
Is the foreach actually looping for each data row? You have not provided enough detail to help you debug this.

Third, Check the query execution method. I dont think its going to return the vorder_id
[ExecuteNonQuery()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5349114/executenonquery)

Finally, the vorderid is going to change for each record inserted and the text would only show the last vorderid inserted.

Comment: `cmd.Parameters.Add(":vORDER_ID", OracleDbType.Int32, ParameterDirection.ReturnValue);`  out parameter returned from the function
I think foreach loop through the `datagridview` because I add `MessageBox.Show(DGV_INVOICE.RowCount.ToString());` before the `ExecuteNonQuery();` and it show up in-corresponding  to the number of record in the `datagridview`
 for the last point that why I have two table the first table has Order_ID as primary key and it referential integrity to second table  order_details

Comment: finally I don't get the point your  talking about the  Check the query execution method very clear but when I call the function using toad to test it its return order_id and another reason that prove that after it is insert one record it return orderid to interface